Create table that has a sequence column counting from 1 for every different foreign key
Is there a way to define a table that has a sequence column counting from 1 for every different corresponding foreign key column?
I want a "local" serial for every foreign key - sorry for the inaccurate language, but by this I really mean:
Table: book_to_paragraph



book_id
paragraph_id
content




1001
1
"first paragraph..."


1001
2
"second paragraph..."


...
...
...


1002
1
"the next book, first paragraph..."


...
...
...



Table: book_to_info



book_id
name
author




...
...
...


1001
Book A
Adam Smith


1002
Book B
Bob C. Smith


...
...
...



Data definition language: book_to_info
CREATE TABLE book_to_info (
   book_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

   bookName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
   authorName TEXT[],
   pubDate DATE
);

Data definition language: book_to_paragraph
CREATE TABLE book_to_paragraph (
   book_id INTEGER REFERENCES book_to_info(book_id),

   paragraph_id ???, <- This is my question!!!

   content TEXT,
   UNIQUE(book_id, paragraph_id)
);

Any help would be appreciated!

Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Is there a maximum number of chapters? Do authors ever rearrange their works - or are these historical?

you make the column an integer and think of a way to enter the chapter number, so you could insert chapter 23 and then 13 as your program defines the order

This question is similar to: Create unique sequence per set of rows sharing the same foreign key value. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

A serial (or IDENTITY) column is not the right tool for your purpose. Those are meant to handle concurrent write access gracefully, and expressly not to produce a gapless sequence of row numbers, much less one per foreign key. They typically produce strictly monotonically increasing numbers in insert order, but even that isn't guaranteed. The only guarantee: unique numbers per row.
The best solution for you depends on the (undisclosed) exact definition of the use case. Concurrency? Cardinalities? Postgres version? What is immutable, what can change? Inserts/Updates/Deletes? Write patterns? Order criteria? Precise objectives?
See:

Create unique sequence per set of rows sharing the same foreign key value
Serial numbers per group of rows for compound key
Is IDENTITY continuous in new versions of PostgreSQL?

